# iOS 13.4 SDK update Navigation Bar title colour is set to Black?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have a problem with iOS 13.4 update Navigation Bar title is set to Black. the title was set to white in attribute inspector for Navigation Bar before the update but after I update my Xcode to 11.4 and iOS SDK to 13.4.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try setting a font?

Comment: @matt it is not working I tried to set the font in the "title text attribute"  and "large title text attribute" :[.

Comment: OK, well, same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848786/xcode-11-4-navigations-title-color-gone-black-from-storyboard, clearly this is a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a bug in Xcode Interface Builder. Apple release Update for Xcode 11.4.1

from Apple developer release notes

> Interface Builder
>
> Fixed an issue that caused some UINavigationBar appearance properties
>   set in storyboard and XIB documents to be ignored when building with
>   Xcode 11.4. (60883063) (FB7639654)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_1_release_notes

Comment: The background custom color doesn't apply for de background color of de navigation bar like in the question's screenshot blue color

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5 IOS 13 Interesting thing 
its will work only in viewDidLoad & viewWillAppear and not working in viewDidAppear

```
//MARK:- Call this function in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method
setNavBarWhite(viewController: self)
```

this is function

```
func setNavBarWhite(viewController: UIViewController) {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .red
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On your all `xib`s, find the `root navigation bar`, and set their `tint color` to `default`.